# Трудность в разборе абревиатуры

Tags: swift

Подскажите пожалуйста, что значит NS в начале? NSObject и в прочем, просто во всей литературе это идет уже как само собой разумеющееся - а что разумеется я где-то пропустил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NeXTSTEP — объектно-ориентированная многозадачная операционная система, которую разработала компания NeXT Computer для собственных компьютеров (NeXT computers, также известны как «black boxes»).

NeXTSTEP 1.0 была выпущена 18 сентября 1989 года. Последний релиз 3.3 был выпущен в 1995 году и уже работал не только на процессорах семейства Motorola 68000, но и на IBM PC-совместимых x86/Intel, Sun SPARC и HP PA-RISC. Во времена версии 3.2 NeXT объединилась с Sun Microsystems для разработки OpenStep — кросс-платформенного стандарта и инструмента разработки (для Sun Solaris, Microsoft Windows и NeXT-версий ядра Mach), основанного на NeXTSTEP 3.2.

4 февраля 1997 года Apple Computer, приобретя NeXT, использовала OpenStep как основу для Mac OS X. Наследие OpenStep в Mac OS X может быть замечено в среде разработки Cocoa, где классы библиотеки Objective-C имеют приставки NS. Также существует свободный вариант OpenStep — GNUstep.